# Big O complexity of nested loop

Tags: big-o

What could be the big O of this code?

I thought --> n + n/2 + n/3 + .....+1 which is just n, but also looks like O(n^2)

```
public int sums(int n){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n/i; j++) {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why? I get it, but I am not convinced by my explanation. @jmvcollaborator

Comment: @jmvcollaborator That's a very bad analysis, though.

Comment: @KellyBundy agreed. I feel it is n^2, the outside loop will run n times, the inner loop will run n times the worst case, and that's why?

Comment: No I mean it's far better than O(n²), so calling it that is bad.

Comment: @KellyBundy would it be n (1 + 1/2+ 1/3 + ......+1/n) = n ( long) = nlogn?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I do try to follow the instruction to "Avoid answering questions in comments". I only spoke up against the *bad* information.

Comment: @KellyBundy  i posted the answer instead of arguing on the comments.

Comment: @KellyBundy shoot ur super "analysis"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be O(n log n).
n + n/2 + n/3 + ... + 1 = n (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... 1/n),
where (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... 1/n) ~ O(log n).
Reference: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sum-of-the-series-1-frac-1-2-frac-1-3-frac-1-4-frac-1-5-up-to-infinity-How-can-it-be-calculated/answer/Avinash-Sahu-7

Comment: I'd suggest [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) instead.

Comment: as long as there is a nested loop the complexity multiplies instead of sum.

Comment: take a look at the merge sort and read about master method case 2, there makes sense that O(nlogn) but it is totally different than your structure iteration/s. still convinced about O(n^2)

Comment: @jmvcollaborator This answer is correct. Why are you're talking about the master method and some other structure? Do you think there's only one structure that takes O(n log n)? That argument sounds like *"Bananas aren't yellow. Look at tennis balls, they're yellow, but they're totally different than bananas. Still convinced about bananas being red."*

Comment: @KellyBundy you are taking this personal. I have never said that's there only one structure. I'm just trying to elaborate on my response, and as reference i mentioned merge sort https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/ .btw i open to discuss we are all here to learn, no one is a guru :)

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Well I only asked. If that *isn't* your point for bringing up the different stuff, then what *is*?

Answer (score -2):

In general, nested loops fall into the O(n)*O(n) = O(n^2) time complexity order, where one loop takes O(n) and if the function includes loops inside loops, it takes O(n)*O(n) = O(n^2).

Similarly, if the function has ‘m' loops inside the O(n) loop, the order is given by O (n*m), which is referred to as polynomial time complexity function.